Java Dropwizard - org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Committed before 100 Continues
I have service written in Java17 and uses Dropwizard 3.0.8 framework. It is containerized using Docker.
My service is calling an another service, but we do not have any control on that service.
Sometimes the external service sends malformed response or some random reason. And my service starts to throw this exception and we need to restart the entire host to fix it:
2024-10-02_21:30:35.89756 org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse URI query
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:467)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1087)
   at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.buildRequestParameterMap(AccessEvent.java:353)
   at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.getRequestParameterMap(AccessEvent.java:374)
   at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing(AccessEvent.java:615)
   at io.dropwizard.request.logging.async.AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory$1.preprocess(AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory.java:22)
   at io.dropwizard.request.logging.async.AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory$1.preprocess(AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory.java:19)
   at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.append(AsyncAppenderBase.java:165)
   at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:85)
   at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
   at ch.qos.logback.access.jetty.RequestLogImpl.log(RequestLogImpl.java:269)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:911)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:467)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
 Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! Incomplete % encoding
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:359)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:296)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI.decodeQueryTo(HttpURI.java:945)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractQueryParameters(Request.java:498)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:463)
 org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse URI query
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:467)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1087)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.buildRequestParameterMap(AccessEvent.java:353)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.getRequestParameterMap(AccessEvent.java:374)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing(AccessEvent.java:615)
       at io.dropwizard.request.logging.async.AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory$1.preprocess(AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory.java:22)
       at io.dropwizard.request.logging.async.AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory$1.preprocess(AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory.java:19)
       at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.append(AsyncAppenderBase.java:165)
       at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:85)
       at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.jetty.RequestLogImpl.log(RequestLogImpl.java:269)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:911)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:467)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not valid encoding '%./'
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeHexByte(UrlEncoded.java:903)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:355)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:296)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI.decodeQueryTo(HttpURI.java:945)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractQueryParameters(Request.java:498)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:463)
       ... 28 more
 org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Committed before 100 Continues
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:600)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:544)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:447)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1087)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.buildRequestParameterMap(AccessEvent.java:353)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.getRequestParameterMap(AccessEvent.java:374)
       at ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing(AccessEvent.java:615)
       at io.dropwizard.request.logging.async.AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory$1.preprocess(AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory.java:22)
       at io.dropwizard.request.logging.async.AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory$1.preprocess(AsyncAccessEventAppenderFactory.java:19) 

How to resolve/handle this effectively? Also note that we cannot upgrade the Dropwizard version.
List of dependencies:


The error seems to be on the other side, they are probably not properly encoding the URI, so this error happens, if you cannot upgrade the dependency then my suggestion is to implement some error handling for that particular exception, and return a 400 bad request message about the URI not being properly encoded.
For example this would be a BAD encoding: https://example.com/search?query=hello world
and this a good encoding: https://example.com/search?query=hello%20world
